# Nested sums in SymPy

Tags: sympy

Apparently SymPy can't compute this, giving as result NaN

```
t=Symbol('t')
s=Symbol('s')
a=Symbol('a')
k=Symbol('k')
k=2
Sum(binomial(k-t+s,a), (a,s+1,k-1), (s,0,k-2), (t,0,k-1) ).doit()
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: sympy doesn't seem to be good in symbolically summing binomials. Also, the summation for `a` depends on `s`, so probably it is better to set the summation over `s` as a surrounding sum. However, `sum([binomial(k - t + s, a) for s in range(0, k - 2 + 1) for t in range(0, k - 1 + 1) for a in range(s + 1, k - 1 + 1)])` seems to give the desired result.

Comment: This is a bug in sympy. Best to report it on github.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19099

Comment: working with pure symbols and subsequent substitution and simplification works as is pointed out at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19099